# How to simplify the following expression

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

I am attempting to simplify the following expression: `(!A && !B) || (!B && !C) || (C && !A)`. It should simplify to only two terms: `(!A and C) || (!B and !C)`

I have tried applying almost all of the laws and tried different combinations of factoring to see if anything will reduce but it does not lead to the required answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You know `C || !C` is true by the law of excluded middle. Combine that with `!A && !B` to get `!A && !B && (C || !C)`. Distribute to get `(!A && !B && C) || (!A && !B && !C)`. Substitute this back into the original expression to get `(!A && !B && C) || (!A && !B && !C) || (!B && !C) || (C && !A)`.

For any expressions `P` and `Q`, if `P -> Q`, then `P || Q` is the same as just `Q`. You should see that `!A && !B && C` implies `C && !A`, so you can remove the former. Same for `!A && !B && !C` and `!B && !C`. You can now easily reorder the remainder into `(!A && C) || (!B && !C)`.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

(! a && c) || (! b && ! c)

from: 
https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator

EDIT: Sorry I didnt know you were looking for HOT to solve it.

In this case I would suggest using a truth table.
This will probably help you alot:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(!A+%26%26+!B)+%7C%7C+(!B+%26%26+!C)+%7C%7C+(C+%26%26+!A)

Comment: The asker already knows the simplified result, so this is basically a link-only answer.

Comment: Oh he is looking for HOW to refactor it...then I would suggest using a truth table